# Problem with indentation with a section having a RegularExpression

Tags: front-end

I have this line of code (a one-liner to import the Abaqus dispalcements!)

```
displacements = 
 DeleteCases[
   ImportString[
    StringCases[fileStr, 
      RegularExpression[
        "------------------------------\n([.\\s\\S]*)Minimum"] -> \
{"$1"}][[1, 1]], "Table"], {}][[
  All, {1, 3, 4}]];(* drop the 2nd column = U.Magnitude *)
```

This line gives a trouble in the auto-intendation when sometimes the * ) in the RegularExpression matches with an opening (* somewhere earlier.

One solution to correct the wrong formatting (I know) is to delete the *) and retype it.

Anyone else faces such trouble in the front-end? Any way to avoid it?

I am on M8

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can avoid completely it since comments behave like:

```
Here is code (* comment " comment *) more code
```

But you can split the string up:

```
"part1*)part2" == "part1*"<>")part2"
```

**Unrelated observations:**

Although I do find it strange you can't escape "*" nor ")" with "\"

```
"\)" != ")"
"\)" != "\\)" (* Theese  two print as the same *)
StringMatchQ["\)", "\\)"] (* False *)
StringTake["\\)", {1}]    (* "\\" *)
StringTake["\)", {1}]     (* "\)" huh? *)
ToCharacterCode["\)"]     (* {63424} something in unicode PUA *)
""=="\)"                 (* True, displays as "\)"=="\)" on input *)
FullForm[\( 1 \)]         (* "1" *)
```

What is this `\(  \)` thing? EDIT: nevermind, it's `RowBox`